# Copying all the contents of an xcode program to one document

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I have a project where I have to submit all the code comprising my program.

However, I am using xcode and an MVC architecture, so my code is split into different files/folders plus the storyboard itself.

I am wondering if there is anyway for me to see all the lines of code in one document so I can copy and paste my CR easily instead of going through each page and copying its content.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands in the working directory using terminal

```
find . -name "*.swift" -type f -exec cat {} + > "combined.swift"
```

If you just wanted to copy all of them

```
find . -name "*.swift" -type f -exec cat {} + | pbcopy
```